# Node Server Crushed after connecting Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to connect MongoDB with my Node server. I made a cluster and copied the following code into my file:

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://myDb:<password>@cluster0.3kehi.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

[Here is how it looks like in my index file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XygEN.png)

However, my server is crushed after this and I am getting this error.

[Click here to see the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5H5e.png)

This might be a basic problem but I am new to mongo DB. How may I fix it? Can anyone explain why am I getting this error?

Comment: The second link navigates to the same picture as the first one. Please, edit the post.

Comment: Thank you, Artem. I have updated the post. Would you please take a look now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs in your line 5 you are using MongoClient before exporting it. And at line 16 you import it. Just import every module or file which you require at the beginning. And it will work

Comment: I was following a tutorial who worked like this. (Though he didn't show whether he had the same error). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

try and change ---password---- in brackets and actually type in your DB password on the const uri = " "